# How to split lines that contain multiple records using bash scripting

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file of the form:

```
Heading1 Heading2 A1 A2 B1 B2 
Heading3 Heading4 A3 A4 B3 B4 C1 C2
```

etc

Each lines contains multiple records belonging to the same headers. What I'm trying to do is split these records preserving their headings. In the example above I would like to produce the following:

```
Heading1 Heading2 A1 A2
Heading1 Heading2 B1 B2 
Heading3 Heading4 A3 A4
Heading3 Heading4 B3 B4
Heading3 Heading4 C1 C2
```

My main problem is that the number of records per line is not constant.

**Edit:** Every line has 2 headings and N number of records each one of them is represented with 2 fields. So the general form of lines' length is 2+2*N. So it is always even

Comment: how this line `Heading1 Heading2 A1 A2 B1 B2 A3` should be processed?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean: could be there an odd number of fields? 3, 5, 7, 9 ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention. That is actually important. Every line has 2 headings and N number of records each one of them is represented with 2 fields. So the general form of fields' length is 2+2*N. So it is always even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short ***awk*** solution:

```
awk '{ for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2) print $1,$2,$i,$(i+1) }' file
```

The output:

```
Heading1 Heading2 A1 A2
Heading1 Heading2 B1 B2
Heading3 Heading4 A3 A4
Heading3 Heading4 B3 B4
Heading3 Heading4 C1 C2
```

---

- `for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2)` - iterating through the fields starting from the 3rd (`i+=2` - iterating pairwise)

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=2)print $1,$2,$i,$(i+1)}' file
```

`NF` is number of fields in line and `$i` you can use field with number i.

Comment: 12 seconds difference (again)

Comment: damn :D recapthca appeared

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r; do
    read -r h1 h2 rest <<< "$REPLY"
    while [ -n "$rest" ]; do
        read -r x1 x2 rest <<< "$rest"
        printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "$h1" "$h2" "$x1" "$x2"
    done
done
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @EdMorton How does that apply to my answer (except for performance, which I don't care about in this example as there already are other answers using awk)?

Comment: idk if there's additional issues with it but it's lengthier to write and slower to execute than an awk solution so there's just no reason to even consider it given the OP has tagged her question with awk and so we know an awk solution (which is better in every way than nested shell loops) is acceptable. It's simply not something that you should do.

Comment: @EdMorton On the other hand, the question title says "using bash scripting". And if we're going for speed, wouldn't a perl solution be even better?

Comment: Feel free to post a perl solution. It won't be noticably faster than the awk solution (and vice-versa) but at least it'd be something reasonable to consider, though the OP may not have perl available since it doesn't come as standard with all UNIX installations, unlike awk which we also KNOW the OP has since she tagged her question with it. Usually when people talk about bash/shell scripting they simply mean including standard UNIX tools like sed and awk, they do not mean using only shell builtins.

Comment: @EdMorton Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^ ]* ){2})(([^ ]* ){2})/\1\3\n\1/;P;D;' file
```